# Dynamic form elements to an displayField in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm working on a application where users can be placed in a group. The groups can be added/edited in the database so these are dynamic. I've got the following form:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->setMethod('post')
         ->setAttrib('id', 'userGroup');

    //get the stuff out of the db
    $group = new Application_Model_GroupMapper();
    $disciplines = $group->fetchAll(array(
        'type' => 'discipline',
        'orderby' => 'g.name',
        'sort' => 'ASC'
    ));

    $disciplineFields = array();
    foreach($disciplines as $row):
        $el = $row->name;
        $this->addElement('checkbox', $el, array(
            'required'      => false,
            'label'         => $el,
            'class'         => 'inputCheckbox'
        ));
        $this->$el->setCheckedValue('true');
        $this->$el->setUnCheckedValue('false');

        array_push($disciplineFields,$el);
    endforeach;

    //discipline information
    $this->addDisplayGroup(
        $disciplineFields,
        'disciplineInformation',
        array('legend' => 'Discipline')
    );
```

**BUT** I get the error:

> No valid elements specified for display group

Well that's strange because when i count my array **$disciplineFields** it has 4 items and the fields are echoed when I'm removing the displayGroup line. Also when I modify the displayGroup line to

```
//discipline information
$this->addDisplayGroup(
    array('Schipper'), //this is one of the records in the database
    'disciplineInformation',
    array('legend' => 'Discipline')
);
```

The 'Schipper' field is showed in the fieldset/displayGroup.

Why is this not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not the answer of your question, but you're using strange PHP syntax : foreach():/endforeach;, array_push... Why not use foreach() {/} and $disciplineFields[] = $el ?

Comment: I'd like to see clearly where a foreach will end, just a syntax I've mad my own. Using the[] method is easier, that's totally true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a breakpoint on Zend_Form::addDisplayGroup and debug it. I see nothing wrong in your code, perhaps your data are not correctly retrieved.

If you make a `Zend_Debug::dump` on `disciplines`, what is displayed ?

And you should pass your discipline via a setDisciplines method of your form instead of hard code it in the init.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in one of my forms. The reason was that I added to the form had a private attribute named _(name of the displayGroup). Imagine in your case you have a private property name named _disciplineInformation. Somehow that created a problem and I was getting the same result you're getting.

I'd suggest yo change the name on the display group to something like disciplineInformationToTest and see if, as the name says, it passes the classic CTRL-R test.

Hopefully this will work; if not please add the full Exception dump in the question.